# Show that if this nonbinding constraint is deleted, it is possible that $\bar{x}$ is not even a local minimum

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-system, karush-kuhn-tucker, nonlinear-analysis

Hello guys I am looking for some help for this nonlinear problem

Let $\bar{x}$ be an optimal solution to the problem of minimizing $f(x)$ subject to $g_{i}(x)\leq0, i=1,...,m$ and $h_{i}(x)=0, i=1,...,l$. Suppose that $g_{k}(\bar{x})<0$ for some $k\in$ {1,...,m}.

Show that if this nonbinding constraint is deleted, it is possible that $\bar{x}$ is not even a local minimum for the resulting problem.[Hint: Consider $g_{k}(\bar{x})=-1$ and $g_{k}(x)=1$ for $x\neq\bar{x}$].

Show that if all problem-defining functions are continuous, then, by deleting nonbinding constraints, X remains at least a local optimal solution.

I did that with an example

min $-x$

$g_{1}= 1/2 - x \leq 0$

$g_{2}=x^{2}-1=0$

So if i apply KKT conditions the optimal is $\bar{x}= 1  (\lambda_{1}=0,\lambda_{2}=1/2)$

and when i delete $g_{1}$ the solution is $\bar{x}= -1(\lambda=-1/2)$

But i am not sure if these is right, and for the second part i don't have idea

Comment: if you delete $g_1$, the solution is still $\bar{x}=1$, right?

Comment: Could be, but also is true with  x=-1, i'm stuck